# Learning OOP PHP: Identifying Classes, Associations for a Quiz System

Tags: php, oop

I'm developing PHP web applications for quite long but now learning OOP approach. To learn and practice, I'm developing a simple web app of "Multiple Choice Questions". When a registered user logs in, he is presented with a list of Quizzes. He selects one and gets questions with multiple answers with any one of them correct.

My questions are:

1. What are the rules to identify Classes? I think "Quiz", "Questions"
   and "Answers" can be declared classes. Am I right?
2. What'll be association types among these classes (or the ones which
   you'll suggest). What are the rules to identify association?
3. How to separate or present System Classes (e.g. database, validation
   classes) and Business Domain Classes?

I'll be grateful if answers could be provided in the context of Quiz system as I have read a lot about "Animal-Dog" Class examples... Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: An excellent book, although it isn't PHP specific, is Domain Driven Design by Eric Evans. In that book he covers many of the questions you are asking like how to identify domain classes and separate layers of concern.

Answer (score 3):

One particular flavour of OOP you'll find helpful is the [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm.

Classes in PHP are typically representations of 'objects', or things that ideally fulfil a certain task. A collection of them may work together to provide a more comprehensive functionality, while being of little use in isolation.

In MVC, these classes are generally split into (in simplified terms):

- **Models**: classes that help you work with your database. You'll have one model for each table, and each model will provide you the ability to save and retrieve data, as well as manipulate it before and after the fact. In your case, a Question will be a model, and it might contain the question itself, and an answer.
- **Views**: these aren't classes, but your raw HTML templates that have data from your models injected via a controller. In your case, one view may be a question view. Another may represent the index page. Yet another may present the results of the questionnaire.
- **Controllers**: classes that act as a middle man between your view and your model. They'll fetch data from the relevant models and pass it to the view. In your case, this may be a Quiz controller. It'll fetch the requested question from the database and provide it to the view, and when the answer is submitted, the controller will pass it to the model to see if it's correct, and act accordingly.

Behind this MCV resides a framework (pre-made, or one you rolled yourself) that provides a number of libraries and abstraction layers to help you focus on your application logic. So there'll be database abstractions like ActiveRecord, there'll be wrappers for commonly used procedural functions, presented in an OOP context, there'll be templating systems to help pass data to your view and format it, and so on.

If you want to head in this direction, consider using an existing framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org) or[CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com) to give you a headstart. They'll familiarise you with OOP (to some extent) and how using classes can be beneficial for larger projects.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I see it, OOP tries to make things more simple, more understanable and more readable for us, programmers.

There arent rules to identify classes. Every programmer can implement different classes to a similar project. When I decide which classes to implement, I will be asking myself questions
like:

- What functions do I need to implement ?
- Do I have functions that provide support for a similar element in my project ?

Here is an example from my current project: I'm making an analytic system that present graphs for users. I've made 2 classes, one is called `analytic` and the second is called `analyticQueries`. The first one is responsible for all of the analytics database updating, and the second is responsible for taking data from the database and prepare it for the graphical engine.

Why didn't I make a single `database` class ? well, I thought It would be too heavy, and as I see it, there are 2 subjects that need to be seperated to better understand the program's way of work: one is writing the database and second is reading from it.

Another way of thinking of classes (And also a good way of planning your database) is asking these questions:

- Who is using the project ?
- What are the action of those who are using it ?
- Who is using who ? (It can help you for making associations. In my project, both of the analytic classes are connecting to the database. I could make a third `DBConnection` class and include it in both of the classes, but I thought that it will not be that big and it is not something that is enough central in the project that needs its own class).

In your website, the users are people who log in, so you'll sure need a `user` table in your database. You will sure need a `questions` table and maybe `answers` table.

You can decide you want classes based on your database, for instance `userManager` can be a class with function responsible on all of the users actions (Login, update details, etc...) and have a `questionManager` that will handle questions presenting and validating answers.